# How to parse correctly an input type object - an array of checkboxes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a list of objects of type 'input'.
I used JSON.stringify(myObject) to stringify. debug shows it is doing ok.
I save the object in my localstorage and then try to parse it to get the object back. I got empty arrays.

```
function saveCheckBoxes(){
        checkBoxStorage = window.localStorage;
        var chkbxsObj  = $("input:checkbox"); 
        const chkbxsArrObj = Object.keys(chkbxsObj).map(i => chkbxsObj[i]); //array che contiene tutti gli oggetti checkbox
        var arrayChecked = []; //array che conterrà gli id dei checkbox segnati
        var chkbxsArr = []; //array che conterrà gli id rappresentanti tutti i checkbox


        for(var i=0;i<chkbxsArrObj.length; i++){
            if(chkbxsArrObj[i].checked == true){
                arrayChecked.push(chkbxsArrObj[i].id);
//              chkbxsArr.splice(i,1);
            }else{
                chkbxsArr.push(chkbxsArrObj[i].id);
            }
        }
        checkBoxStorage.setItem("chkbxsArrObj",JSON.stringify(chkbxsArrObj)); 

       //I get soething like: chbxsArrObj: Array(13) [input#id, input#id, input#id, input#id, ...]

        checkBoxStorage.setItem("chkbxsArr",chkbxsArr);
        checkBoxStorage.setItem("arrayChecked",arrayChecked);
        }
```

Then, I call another method and i try to parse back my objects:

> var chkbxsObj= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("chkbxsArrObj"));

and I get something like:

> chkbxsObj: Array(13) [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ...]

so, empty objects.
Any clue? what should I do to get back my objects?

Comment: change `checkBoxStorage.setItem("chkbxsArrObj",JSON.stringify(chkbxsArrObj));` to`checkBoxStorage.setItem("chkbxsArrObj",JSON.stringify(arrayChecked));` You only need to know which checkboxes are checked. The rest is moot. you can even dump your else statement. Checkboxes are unchecked by default(unless you defined otherwise)

Comment: no, because I need that chkbxsArrObj to be available to another method triggered on next page load.

Comment: You can't transfer a DOM element. Only the values... The DOM element is lost on reload. So you need to save all your essential data you need in a new object, save that in local storage. Then on reload, re-select everything based on saved data etc..

Comment: I had another look at the code and I figured out that the problem is Parsing : checkBoxStorage.setItem("chkbxsArrObj",JSON.stringify(chkbxsArrObj)) returnes an array [{},{},{},{}...]. Therefore I guess the problem is parsing. How can I parse an input object?